# Excel Separator shortcut for numbers not working CTRL + SHIFT + 1

Tags: microsoft-excel

After windows 10 last updates Excel Separator shortcut for numbers not working CTRL + SHIFT + 1

Ex: 55555 into 55.555,00

I'm using this a lot. any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean CTRL+SHIFT+1 (or CTRL+! if you prefer) which applies number format, with thousands separators and two decimal places by default.

Comment: Yes you are right I edited the title :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, after I closed opera browser I was able to use CTRL+SHIFT+1 somehow opera was preventing that shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after getting a new computer. Turned out my decimal separator in the regional settings in the control panel was set to "," when it used to be ".". Therefore Excel didn't recognise numbers as numbers and couldn't format them as such.